# How to fix downloads with `chrome.downloads` extensions' API getting automatically interrupted if download confirmation setting is ON?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser

### Description

I am developing a small Chrome extension and needed to download a file off web. Here's how the script behaves:

1. I initiate the download in my `service_worker` JS file (either on a command event or with no conditionals at all)
2. The download starts
3. The callback runs and receives an ID (which means download starts successfully)
4. The download never completes (`saveAs` dialog never opens even if set to `true`)
5. Upon analyzing the `DownloadItem` object for the returned ID, its `status` is found to be `interrupted` and its reason to be `USER_CANCELED`
6. No errors are reported in either of the consoles -- the page's or the service_worker's -- or the extensions page
7. `chrome.runtime.lastError` is undefined as well.

### Current Config

- `downloads` in the permissions
- `<all_urls>` in host permissions (for debugging)

### Observation

- The download succeeds if:

  - `Ask where to save each file before downloading` setting is turned off and...
  - `filename`/`saveAs` isn't set in passed `DownloadOptions`

But shouldn't the download work nonetheless?

#### Background.js

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"; //random image
  chrome.downloads.download({url, saveAs: true}, (id) => {
    console.log(chrome.downloads.search({id}, (result) => {
      console.log(result)
      console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)
    }))
  })
})
```

Any idea what's going on? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: We can't help you until you show your code, especially the part that checks `chrome.runtime.lastError`. Also, does this happen when all other extensions are disabled? and Incognito mode?

Comment: Hi @Dai I check `lastError` manually in the console as well as part of the `search` callback. I have updated the question with a sample code.

The download completes if `Ask where to save each file before downloading` setting is turned off. SImply disablingother extensions doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think wrapping your anonymous callbacks in `console.log` calls is necessarily a good idea. (Though it sucks that the API doesn't return `Promise<T>`, grr) **EDIT:** Ah, it does support `await` and promises now: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/promises/

Comment: I know @Dai, just using `console.log`s for debugging purposes. And I don't think Promise based APIs have been shipped yet. Docs show `Availability` to be `Pending`.

Comment: @Aniket I am having the same problem.. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: I dropped my project. I didn't find a solution at the time. @domskat @ cliffniff